# Crontab apparently not calling sudo

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04, cron, sudo, openvpn

*tl;dr A bash script which requires SUDO works fine when called manually, but does not work when called by crontab, even though it was add to crontab using* `sudo crontab -e`

I am trying to automate my connection to my vpn proxy such that the vpn connection is turned on at midnight and off at 7:15AM.
In order to automate it, I wrote the following bash script, located at `/usr/local/bin/cloak.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE=/home/declan/log/cloak.log

LogEntry()
    {
        while read data
        do
            echo "$(date "+%Y %m %d %T") ; $data" >>$LOG_FILE 2>&1;
        done
    }

echo "---------------------" | LogEntry

if [ $1 -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "Turning Cloak On" | LogEntry 
    /etc/init.d/openvpn start proxpn.miami | LogEntry
else
    echo "Turning Cloak Off" | LogEntry
    /etc/init.d/openvpn stop | LogEntry
fi

echo "---------------------" | LogEntry
echo " " | LogEntry
```

My vpn is working and I have confirmed that the script is executable and that it works by checking my IP address before and after calls to the script, turning the VPN on (1 as parameter) or off (0 as parameter).

```
declan@mx:~/log$ wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo
74.196.220.81 <<-- This is my real IP address
declan@mx:~/log$ sudo /usr/local/bin/cloak.sh 1 <<-- Turn the VPN on
declan@mx:~/log$ wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo
173.0.8.33 <<-- This is my VPN IP address
declan@mx:~/log$ sudo /usr/local/bin/cloak.sh 0 <<-- Turn the VPN off
declan@mx:~/log$ wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo
74.196.220.81 <<-- Back to my real IP address
declan@mx:~/log$
```

I add this script to cron, using `sudo crontab -e` to ensure that sudo is running the script, with the following lines in the crontab

```
# Cloak on at midnight, off at 7:15AM
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/cloak.sh 1
15 7 * * * /usr/local/bin/cloak.sh 0
```

If I look at the contents of the log, `/home/declan/log/cloak.log`, it shows that the cron job is being executed at the correct time.

The problem is that when I check my IP address after the cron job tries to start the VPN, my real IP address is still being used. My only guess is that somehow the cron job is not being called with sudo rights, but I can't understand why.

Any help would be appreciated. I am also open to any suggestions on alternative approaches, different scripts, etc...

Thanks
Declan

Comment: Everything in root's crontab file will be executed with root permissions. There must be some other reason the script is failing.

Comment: but the script runs fine when I execute it manually from the CLI. (as in the example in the middle of my question).

Comment: For some reason the script is sensitive to whether it's being run interactively or from cron.

Comment: I should also mention that I have other entries in root's crontab that do run correctly. So it is some weid interplay between my script and crontab.

Comment: Most likely your script depends on one or more environmental variables which are not set in the `cron` environment. You could try `sudo -s`, then `unset $(env | sed '/^PATH=/d; s/=.*//')` to clear your environment (except PATH) and then run your script to see what happens.

Comment: Also, your `LogEntry` function might not work as expected due to the output of your `vpn` program not being line buffered. Normally the solution would be to use `setbuf -oL` to run the program, but I don't think this will work since the call is indirect.

Comment: @Declan_K check the [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) which contains a section about sudo. Chances are sudo is configured to require a tty. [Try letting it run without it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/how-to-disable-requiretty-for-a-single-command-in-sudoers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following to my crontab and now everything is working as intended.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: Sounds like something in the script is invoking a program that isn't in the default `$PATH`. (This may require some experimentation, but) you might consider using absolute paths in the script instead of setting `$PATH` in the crontab.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that its in the init.d script that was installed with openvpn. I'm not confident enough in my bash skills to mess with that, so I'm going to be content with this solution..for now.. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

The question is... "why use sudo?" you need a service restart which is a root operation. Edit the /etc/crontab and add the line like this:

```
0 0 * * * root /usr/local/bin/cloak.sh 1
15 7 * * * root /usr/local/bin/cloak.sh 0
```

and it should it work.

Comment: He's using sudo to put it in root's crontab, which is equivalent to a root entry in /etc/crontab.